# How to get a Specific NSDictionary Object from a separate View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

In my app I have a View Controller that searches for jobs around the country using a Web Service. I'm able to correctly call the service and populate my FoundJobsTableViewController like so:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"push"])
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.usa.gov/jobs/search.json?query=%@+jobs+in+%@", [jobDescription text], [location text]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableArray *jobsCallArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *positionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *theJob in jobsCallArray)
    {
        NSString *jobDesc = theJob[@"position_title"];
        [positionArray addObject:jobDesc];
    }

    FoundJobsTableViewController *detailVC = (FoundJobsTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

    [detailVC  setArray:positionArray];



}
}
```

However, now I want to populate my DetailViewController with a bunch of data from the web service filtered by the search terms from the user. I've attempted this problem in a variety of ways, however I can't just get the values I want in a separate view controller. How can I go about this?

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: whats wrong with a delegate

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend that you structure your program so that your data is stored in another object.  This object can provide both properties for accessing the data and methods for executing the queries.  You can then either pass this object between your view controllers using properties or (my preferred approach) store it as a property of your app delegate, which you can then access using something like `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.mydata`

The way you have it at the moment your data is stored in your method variables, which, as you have found, makes it hard to access.

Also, while I appreciate that this may be early days for your program's development, executing network queries that could take a long time (or may even fail) is not a guide idea in prepareForSegue.  I would suggest that when the user touches the 'search' button (or whatever it is that initiates the search) that you would display some sort of activity indicator for the user and then execute the search via a method on your data object.  Then if the search fails or times out you can return an appropriate message or if it completes successfully you can then initiate the segue.  This approach will mean manually triggering the segue rather than relying on the storyboard to do it for you.